# Python threads: How to represent data that a thread should read-only?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-multithreading

I'm building a tkinter app which runs a daemon thread alongside it's `mainloop()`, where most of the shared data between the threads is going through queues.

I've created the other thread class in another `.py` file, and I'm importing it in the main file.

In the main file, I have a `SETTINGS` dict which the user update using the GUI, and I need the other thread to be able to read it while not modifying it.

I thought about `RLock`, but from my understanding it is usually used by both of the threads and might be a little confusing to understand in the future.

I'm looking for something simple, must be a python builtin solution.

**EDIT:** I'll add that the other thread will access the dict all the time, and shouldn't be aware when the main thread updates it.

Comment: You could maybe give the other thread access to a copy of the settings.

Comment: I need to code to be as fast as possible, don't want to create other copies of the same information. Also, I need the other thread the be able to read the information without the main thread to send it over and over.

Comment: You could use a subclass of `collections.UserDict` which stores the id of the owner thread and then checks in ``__setitem__`` that the current thread is the owner thread. What should happen if a thread tries to write? raise exception? silently fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `SETTINGS` global variable.

Since it's user updated, there won't be thread safety problem when it's modified. And just (only) READ the variable in any other places you want.

Comment: But how will it be visible to the other thread? This thread is a class declared in another module (which I import directly and init in the main module)

Comment: Add a new argument in your thread `__init__`, and just pass it into the thread